# Use Google Cloud with Nativescript

Tags: node.js, mobile, google-cloud-datastore, nativescript

I'm looking for a way to integrate Google Cloud, especially Datastore with a nativescript application. 
Is it possible to use the Node.js library : https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client_libraries_install_nodejs

Regards,
Franck

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can perfectly integrate it with Google Datastore. I created a library to be able to define Model Schemas (gstore-node) and a small utility to create RESTful API endpoints for the entities on the Datastore (gstore-api).
See if those can help you.